# Angular2 issue in zone.js

Tags: javascript, .net, angular, angular2-http

I am trying to implement a login authentication service from this [repo](https://github.com/cornflourblue/angular2-jwt-authentication-example).

So I copied the `folders helpers, services, models` and `guards` into my `app` folder. Then I changed a my `login` `component` and `html`. Last, I modified my `app.module`.

This is the `app.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule }                     from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }                from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }    from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent }                 from './app.component';
import { Ng2BootstrapModule }           from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
import { NAV_DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES }      from './shared/nav-dropdown.directive';

import { ChartsModule }                 from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts';
import { SIDEBAR_TOGGLE_DIRECTIVES }    from './shared/sidebar.directive';
import { AsideToggleDirective }         from './shared/aside.directive';
import { BreadcrumbsComponent }         from './shared/breadcrumb.component';
import { routing }                      from './app.routing';

//Layouts
import { FullLayoutComponent }          from './layouts/full-layout.component';
import { SimpleLayoutComponent }        from './layouts/simple-layout.component';

//Main view
import { DashboardComponent }           from './dashboard/dashboard.component';

//Components
import { ButtonsComponent }             from './components/buttons.component';
import { CardsComponent }               from './components/cards.component';
import { FormsComponent }               from './components/forms.component';
import { SocialButtonsComponent }       from './components/social-buttons.component';
import { SwitchesComponent }            from './components/switches.component';
import { TablesComponent }              from './components/tables.component';

//Icons
import { FontAwesomeComponent }         from './icons/font-awesome.component';
import { SimpleLineIconsComponent }     from './icons/simple-line-icons.component';

//Widgets
import { WidgetsComponent }             from './widgets/widgets.component';

//Charts
import { ChartsComponent }              from './charts/charts.component';

//Pages
import { p404Component }                from './pages/404.component';
import { p500Component }                from './pages/500.component';
import { LoginComponent }               from './pages/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent }            from './pages/register.component';

// used to create fake backend
import { fakeBackendProvider } from './_helpers/index';
import { MockBackend, MockConnection } from '@angular/http/testing';
import { BaseRequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

import { AuthGuard } from './_guards/index';
import { AuthenticationService, UserService } from './_services/index';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    routing,
    Ng2BootstrapModule,
    ChartsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FullLayoutComponent,
    SimpleLayoutComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    ButtonsComponent,
    CardsComponent,
    FormsComponent,
    SocialButtonsComponent,
    SwitchesComponent,
    TablesComponent,
    FontAwesomeComponent,
    SimpleLineIconsComponent,
    WidgetsComponent,
    ChartsComponent,
    p404Component,
    p500Component,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    NAV_DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES,
    BreadcrumbsComponent,
    SIDEBAR_TOGGLE_DIRECTIVES,
    AsideToggleDirective
  ],
  providers: [
      AuthGuard,
      AuthenticationService,
      UserService,

      // providers used to create fake backend
      fakeBackendProvider,
      MockBackend,
      BaseRequestOptions
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I tested the sample applicattion and it worked fine, but I am trying to migrate it to my project.

I thought it could be a version problem, but `packages.json` with `zone.js` and `systemjs`, but I downgraded them and the problem persists in the same line:

> zone.js:203 Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected token <(…)

You can test it from [here](https://github.com/FacundoGFlores/Angular2_ASPCORE/tree/authentication) if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the `systemjs.config.js` and the problem was solved.

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: 'app',
            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/http/testing': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http-testing.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            // other libraries
            'rxjs':                       'npm:rxjs',
            'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api',
            'moment':                     'npm:moment/moment.js',
            'ng2-charts':                 'npm:ng2-charts'
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
                main: './index.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'ng2-charts': {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```